# i used jQuery slideDown to create a drop down

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu

There is problem:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvYqk.gif)

sorry this is Persian

```js
        $("#menu-item-225").mouseover(function(){
      $(".Slider-menu").slideDown("slow")
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the main function to make it functional... Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(() =>{
   $("#menu-item-225").mouseover(function(){
      $(".Slider-menu").slideDown("slow");
   });
});
```

There is a little trick to make this happen if you dont want to move قالب مانی you should make the position of your navigation element absolute... Like this:

```
.navigation__element{
  position: absolute;
}
```

I hope it helps...